# Populating data from database into multiple colums equally?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to populate two different container equally with data coming from the database. Putting 5 locations in the first container and 6 at the second. Every time that run this code, it populates all into the left container. 
Any Ideas what am I missing?

```js
shopDataContext dc = new shopDataContext();
var areas = (from s in dc.Areas select s);
String content = "";
foreach(var a in areas) {
    if (a.id >= 1 && a.id <= 6) {
      content += "<div><h3>" + a.Tittle + "</h3>";
      var aStores = (from s in dc.Stores where s.areaid == a.id select s);
      foreach(var s in aStores) {
        content += "<p>" + s.Tittle + "</p>";
      }
      leftContent.InnerHtml = leftContent.InnerHtml + content;
    } else {
      content += "<div><h3>" + a.Tittle + "</h3>";
      var aStores = (from s in dc.Stores where s.areaid == a.id select s);
      foreach(var s in aStores) {
        content += "<p>" + s.Tittle + "</p>";
      }
      rightContent.InnerHtml = rightContent.InnerHtml + content;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You miss some end brackets which are obvious when using the snippet editor `<>` and TIDYing your code. Please click that `<>` editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure, that your areas contain an item with id < 1 or id > 6?

Comment: It is not about your question but, you don't need var areas = (from s in dc.Areas select s); only areas=dc.Areas is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to reset the added content in each iteration of the loop:

```
...
foreach(var a in areas) {
    string content = "";
    if (a.id >= 1 && a.id <= 6) {
      ...
    }
}
....
```

Otherwise the content is added several times.

Comment: Thanks very much Simon D. It was exactly what I was looking for!